# Where to get etrogim in the US after Sukkot

Tags: product-recommendation, lulav-etrog-arba-minim

NPR ran an [article](http://www.npr.org/blogs/thesalt/2014/10/03/353311090/the-birth-and-afterlife-of-israels-precious-etrog-fruit) about the etrog market in the Jewish world. They mention that after chag, etrogim cost about $2 a pound (not to mention the ones which were passul to begin with). Does anyone know where to purchase etrogim in the US for human consumption?

Comment: Don't look for the ones which were being sold for the Mitzva. They put oodles of pesticides on them to avoid black dots

Comment: @Double AA does that get removed by scrubbing with soap and water? I don't want to poison my friends and family with esrog liquor poisoning. Liver poisoning is ok.

Comment: I've seen citrons for sale.  [Apparently](http://gretastories.blogspot.com/2008/12/tale-of-citron-true-hilarious-story.html) they are used in Christmas fruit cakes.  Also, [Buddha's hand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddha%27s_hand) smells the same and I assume it tastes the same, too.  It's easier to find in grocery stores.

Comment: [tag:product-recommendation]? The product is known; the means of acquisition is the sought recommendation.

Comment: @msh210, I didn't have an alternate tag to use and I was not in bounds to create one.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt i have a contact that will sell you etrogim after sukkot. Contact me and i will shar ehis info

Comment: @Aaron, that's great! I'm going to put off getting the info for a few days, I've got a lot of post-semester stuff on my plate right now though.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because according to the top voted answer on meta http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3747/8775 questions are on topic "when they specifically relate to fulfillment of a Jewish obligation" "But in general, I think a question is in scope here if it passes the tests, "Does it matter whether this is Jewish?" and "Would this get [roughly] the same answer on another SE site as here?" This question fails these criteria.

Comment: @mevaqesh, agreed

Answer (score 3):

I know what I state will seem "over simplified", but seriously, I would contact some shuls immediately after Yom Tov, esp. Hoshannah Rabbah morning, if you can.

Most congregants leave their etrogim in the shul after davening Hoshannah Rabbah. I can't say who takes them away, but in my shul, I suspect that since the janitor cleans the shul, he may just throw them into the trash! Point is, if you can at least contact the shul and get the rabbi or someone in charge, you can probably get a bunch of etrogim for free!

Some communities such as Flatbush, Teaneck, Passaic, Baltimore, etc. have web post forums. Look them up in Google. You may want to place a posting to the effect - "If you're disposing of your etrog, please contact me ... etc." You may get more responses than you care to handle, actually.

Request - if you collect a bunch of etrogim and make jelly, I request a jar. I haven't had this in years!

I can't agree or disagree with @DoubleAA's comment about pesticides. But, I have eaten etrogim, before, and I had no ill effects other than a bitter taste in my mouth, and I think it was from the etrog and not DDT. FYI - Someone told me that the bracha is "shehakol" and not "ha'etz" as it's uncommon to eat raw etrogim.

Answer (score 1):

I have friends that are esrog dealers so I get them for free after sales end. I suggest you be all friendly-like to your local seller and see where that gets you.

Comment: A lot of times esrog dealers will have leftovers, as I've found. One time my brother's lulav fell on Sukkos and broke, and we got it replaced for free from our friend the esrog dealer. It pays to have friends in the right places :)

Comment: @Shokhet How do you break a Lulav on the latter days of Sukkot?

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm not sure....this happened a while back so the details are fuzzy. It may have happened on the first day (possibly during Hoshanos), and the Rav advised to replace it for the second day.

Answer (score 1):

In the Kosher stores around my area, bunches of Esrogim are sold after Sukkos.

Comment: Where's your area?